# Message property missing from post object retrieved?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, post, message

I am trying to retrieve all comments of a certain user (not on a specific post but in a general way) using the Graph API.

I have come to understand that I need to query a user's posts and that the result will also contain that user's comments.
I manage to retrieve the list of posts for a specific user and I do see the comments the user posted.
However, the message property is always missing:

```
{
   "id": "100005227004296_112167712300795",
   "from": {
      "name": "Karen Amebbgkdbif Lausen",
      "id": "100005227004296"
   },
   "story": "\"Karens erster Kommentar zu...\" on Mike Amebkhdchid Letuchysky's photo.",
   "story_tags": {
      "35": [
         {
            "id": "100005200843894",
            "name": "Mike Amebkhdchid Letuchysky",
            "offset": 35,
            "length": 27,
            "type": "user"
         }
      ]
   },
   "privacy": {
      "value": ""
   },
   "type": "status",
   "application": {
      "name": "Photos",
      "id": "2305272732"
   },
   "created_time": "2013-02-17T20:59:52+0000",
   "updated_time": "2013-02-17T20:59:52+0000",
   "comments": {
      "count": 0
   }
}
```

The story property contains a part of the message, but not all of it.

How can I access the full comment (text)?

Thanks in advance!
Alex

Answer (score 0):

You may need to pull back additional properties such as type, status_type and description. If you like a link or comment on something else where and that appears in your timeline it can be returned from the post feed.

Try these fields in the graph API explorer to see what data is returned:

```
   id,created_time,from,message,type,description,story,status_type
```